# How to put multiple input fields in one row using bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there any bootstrap3 way to put all these fileds into one row? If it's possible I want to keep the `input-group` solution too.

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" required>
    <input type="text" name="tel" placeholder="Phone" class="form-control">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" class="form-control">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="fa fa-btn fa-plus"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

Is this possible without `CSS` style hacking?

Comment: remove the `.form-control` class? http://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/BRbBXR

Comment: or put them in row/col's? http://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/QvoWLa

Comment: Use [grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic).

Comment: if I remove `.form-control` class, then fields lose their formatting...

Comment: change the display and width: https://jsfiddle.net/c7m4jem4/

Comment: Check out http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline and http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in this way

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" required>
    <input type="text" name="tel" placeholder="Phone" class="form-control">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" class="form-control">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="fa fa-btn fa-plus"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: The `.input-group` in this case seems not useful (if you are not using it for another reason), and thats why I provided to you just `.form-inline`